# CSS Floating Footer?

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I've been trying to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516910/how-can-i-force-my-footer-to-stick-to-the-bottom-of-any-page-in-css) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679146/force-footer-on-bottom-on-pages-with-little-content) on the below code with little success. When there is scrolling content in the div above the footer, the footer floats around in the middle of the scrollable content. I'm sure that there is a simpler solution than what I'm trying below:

```css
.container {
  width: 964px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
#footer-container {
  background-color: #000000;
}

#footer-container #footer {
  background: url("http://www.me.com/common/commonspot/templates/images/chrome/logos/footer-logo.png") no-repeat scroll 20px 23px #000;
  padding-bottom: 49px;
}
#footer .top {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #7F7F7F;
  margin-left: 82px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  padding-top: 33px;
}
#footer .text-logo {
  background: url("http://www.me.com/common/commonspot/templates/images/chrome/logos/text-logo.png") no-repeat croll 0 0 transparent;
  float: left;
  height: 28px;
  width: 176px;
}
#footer .slogan {
  background: url("http://www.me.com/common/commonspot/templates/images/chrome/logos/slogan.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  float: right;
  height: 12px;
  margin-top: 14px;
  width: 259px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#footer .links {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 81px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}
#footer .links a {
  color: #fff;
}
#footer .links li {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#footer .social {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 37px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 14px;
}
#footer .social li {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#footer .social a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 26px;
}
#footer .social .facebook {
  background: url("http://www.me.com/common/commonspot/templates/images/chrome/utils/social_v2.png") no-repeat scroll 0px 4px transparent;
}
#footer .social .twitter {
  background: url("http://www.me.com/common/commonspot/templates/images/chrome/utils/social_v2.png") no-repeat scroll 0px -20px transparent;
}
#footer .social .youtube {
  background: url("http://www.me.com/common/commonspot/templates/images/chrome/utils/social_v2.png") no-repeat scroll 4px -42px transparent;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
#footer .social .itunes {
  background: url("http://www.me.com/common/commonspot/templates/images/chrome/utils/social_v2.png") no-repeat scroll 4px -66px transparent;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
#footer .updated {
  clear: right;
  color: #9B9B9B;
  float: right;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 14px;
}
#footer-container ul li {
  text-align: left
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-container" style="margin: 0 auto; width: auto;" align="center" background-color="#000000" ;>
  <div id="footer" class="chrome-center clearfix">
    <div class="top clearfix">
      <a href="http://www.me.com/">
        <div class="text-logo"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="slogan"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="links">
      <li><a href="/faqs.htm">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/aboutus/website-policies.htm">Website Policies</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/contacts.htm">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="youtube"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/Mywebsite">YouTube</a>
      </li>
      <li class="itunes"><a href="http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewArtistLegacy?cc=us&amp;id=216751324">iTunes</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/mywebsite">Facebook</a>
      </li>
      <li class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/mywebsite">Twitter</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="updated">
      <p>Last Updated: 03/06/2015</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--! end of #footer-->
</div>
<!--! end of #footer-container -->
```

Comment: add position:fixed to your footer

Comment: why don't you just scroll your container? e.g. http://rachelgallen.com/scrollheader.html

Comment: tried that. The footer stays fixed, but fixed on the bottom of the page, and the scroll container becomes too narrow to show any content.

Comment: here's what this looks like: http://grsm.nps.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?q=trails. Footer starts on line 1855

Comment: @tpcolson can you provide jsfiddle.?

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara  negative,pretty limited to what we can deploy within the CMS.

Comment: @tpcolson is your basic code working properly .?

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara yes, when I remove the footer element, everything works, and the footer works by itself independently.

Comment: @tpcolson hi <div id="footer-container" **style="margin: 0 auto; width: auto;** may  b prevent so try after removing margin: 0 auto; this might work for you

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara removed margin: 0 auto, still the same problem.

Comment: @tpcolson then need to see the working demo can you provide problamatic code on live.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83879/discussion-between-tpcolson-and-himesh-aadeshara).

Comment: @tpcolson having some reason so that can't be on chat

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara  grsm.nps.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?q=trails