# How to make a footer fixed at bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, footer

I am using footer in my project. I am using c#.net mvc.

I insert the footer. But I have problem in it.

When Body have low content means, the footer goes up. i.e. Below the body content. I want footer to be fixed at bottom of the page if body contains low content.

How can I achieve it?

```css
.footer {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border-top: 1px solid #e7eaec;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  Bottom Page
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use new properties and values from CSS3.

For instance :

```
<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

For the CSS :

```
.container {
    min-height: 90vh;
}

.footer {
    height: 10vh;
}
```

This way, your footer will always be at the bottom, even if your container is null

Comment: this makes the height of your footer dynamic, might not be what you whant, also might turn out to be lower then your footer content height....

Comment: It's still a solution, he didn't specify those points. And about the footer content, you can adapt it to it. You also have media queries to handle specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

@Nivitha G Please find following code.I hope you are expecting the same.

```css
footer {
  background: #2db34a;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>Fixed Footer</footer>
```

Comment: This isn't much use.  It appears *over the top* of any content.

Comment: @ freedomn-m Agree with you. Can you please tell me how can we do it in a better way?

Comment: there's already a number of duplicates in SO

Comment: Which one do you prefer among them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `site-footer` class to create a sticky footer:

```
<div class="page-wrap">  
  Content!      
</div>
<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you whant your footer to scroll below the fold as well but never be higher then the bottom of the window you can do something like this:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

and then

```
html{
  height:100%;
}
body{
  min-height:100%;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
}

footer{
  background: #ccc;
  height:30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%
}

#content{
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ay6jx9yp/

Answer (score 0):

```
   Will you please try by making this.

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here is one of the [answered link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679146/force-footer-on-bottom-on-pages-with-little-content) similar to your problem: